# How I get an element from instagram with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I am working on a automatic instagram follower bot. It is a exercise from the 100 days of code on Udemy.

I have a problem with the element. I cant find the followertag.

[Profile from instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BsIR.png)

I use the following code:

```
    def find_follower(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{SIMILAR_ACCOUNT}")
        time.sleep(2)                                       
        path = self.driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="_aa_c")
        print(path.text)

    
        this_is_what_I_want = self.driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//a[@href]") 
        for item in next2:
            element = item.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="span").get_attribute("_ac2a _ac2b").click()
```

I want to push the follower link. I know the code is wrong. I tried so many tags but nothing works.

Does someone has any idea? Thank you very much

Best regards

Levin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click the "followers" button try this:

```py
self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='followers']").click()
```

Or if you prefer XPath

```py
self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'followers')]").click()
```

Comment: I know :) you are welcome!